# Magento 2: In which database table are the payment methods stored?

Tags: magento2, php, database

I'm working on a **custom module** that uses a **database table** that have the **foreign key** of both the **payment methods** and **customer groups**. I don't know which **database table** stores all the **payment methods**.

My Googling skills couldn't find it.

Comment: SELECT entity_id,method FROM `sales_order_payment`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, payment methods are certainly stored in the database, they don't have their own table but are stored in the core_config_data table

To get the payment methods you can do the following:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'payment/%active' ORDER BY path;
```

This will display values with their ACTIVE bit (yes/no):

> payment/paypal_express/active   1
>
> payment/wps_express/active      0

The means that PayPal Express has "Enabled = YES" on Admin
Whilst WPS Express has "Enabled = NO" in the Admin.

I hope this helps with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Payment methods are not stored in the database. Also, customer payment information is not stored in the database. The only exception to this is the Magento Vault but that doesn't sound like what you are asking for and it stores very limited info.

After an order is placed, you can find information regarding transactions in the sales_order_payment table.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not save payment methods, In **core_config_data** you will find your custom payment method's settings but list of payment method you could not find.

Check your third party payment module's below three file.

```
- etc/adminhtml/system.xml ( load for payment method settings)
- etc/payment.xml  (define your payment method)      
- etc/config.xml ( used for save default value)
```

If your are looking for your order payment method in Database.

check quote and order payment table

```
quote_payment
sales_order_payment
sales_creditmemo_grid
sales_invoice_grid
sales_order_grid
sales_shipment_grid
```